# 401 Authorization Error when using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, server

I am trying to retrieve JSON from my app's server which needs a user/password authentication. Does anyone know why I am not being allowed entry into the server? I tried including an authorization header with the credentials needed but still get this error.

```
func retrieveJSON(){
    let login = "login@mail.com"
    let password = "password"
    
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://server/admin/data.json")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let userPasswordString = "\(login):\(password)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedString()
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

[Response message with 401 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUL4R.png)

[Server authorization needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wraV.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant information and code as text rather than as screen shots.

Comment: Attached is the function in question, because I am getting an 401 unauthorized error I think that my authorization header is not working? Please let me know if there is any more information I can add.

Comment: Regarding your question, do you know that this endpoint is definitely using "Basic" authorization? You're just showing us a HTML page for logging in, but that doesn't tell us anything about how its handling authentication. There are lots of ways it could be authenticating...

Comment: Yes, that form doesn't appear to be basic auth; A basic auth prompt would be presented by the browser

Answer (score 1):

Your web site does not appear to be using “basic” auth. It would appear to be using some different authentication scheme, which we cannot determine from an image of the HTML login page.

---

If it were using “Basic” auth (which it likely is not in your particular case), you could simplify the code a bit, removing `NSURL`, `NSMutableURLRequest`, the casts, etc. Also, if you’re going to create a `URLSession`, you will want to `finishTasksAndInvalidate`:

```
func retrieveJSON() {
    let login = "login@mail.com"
    let password = "password"

    let url = URL(string: "http://server/admin/data.json")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)  // use `var` if you really need it to be mutable

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let base64EncodedCredential = (login + ":" + password)
        .data(using: .utf8)!
        .base64EncodedString()
    config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": "Basic " + base64EncodedCredential]

    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        debugPrint(response ?? "No response")
    }
    task.resume()
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

Alternatively, rather than building the `Authorization` header yourself, you can call `CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication` to add authentication headers to a request. And, as an aside, adding the authentication to the request itself, you don’t have to create your own `URLSession`, but can use the shared instance.

```
func retrieveJSON() {
    let login = "login@mail.com"
    let password = "password"

    let url = URL(string: "http://server/admin/data.json")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.updateBasicAuth(for: login, password: password)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        debugPrint(response ?? "No response")
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Where

```
extension URLRequest {

    /// Update request for HTTP authentication
    ///
    /// - parameter username:        The username
    /// - parameter password:        The password
    /// - parameter authentication:  The type of authentication to be applied

    mutating func updateBasicAuth(for username: String, password: String, authentication: String = kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic as String) {
        let message = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, httpMethod! as CFString, url! as CFURL, kCFHTTPVersion1_1).takeRetainedValue()
        if !CFHTTPMessageAddAuthentication(message, nil, username as CFString, password as CFString, authentication as CFString?, false) {
            print("authentication not added")
        }
        if let authorizationString = CFHTTPMessageCopyHeaderFieldValue(message, "Authorization" as CFString)?.takeRetainedValue() {
            setValue(authorizationString as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        } else {
            print("didn't find authentication header")
        }
    }
}
```

---

But refinements to the “Basic” authentication are somewhat academic if your server is using a different authentication scheme.

Comment: The server that I am working with begins with app. For example, http://app.myserver.com/admin/login. Would this also be related to an AWS EC2 (which is also connected to my project)?

Comment: @TariqOliver - If you’re seeing a HTML rendered login page, then it’s exceedingly unlikely that it is actually using “basic” authentication. (Basic auth generally results in a browser-based authentication dialog box, not a HTML one). You really need to look at the docs or source for the server code (or talk to your backend devs) in order to confirm precisely how your server is performing authentication. But “basic” authentication is relatively uncommon in these scenarios. The fact that your “basic” authentication is failing would further suggest that your server is not using that mechanism.